# ssh nested login to other ssh

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh

I have two servers named serverA and serverB where serverB can only be accessed via serverA.

So, first I login to serverA with the command

```
ssh uname@serverA
```

after login in to serverA, I again hit the same command to login to serverB, i.e.

```
ssh uname@serverB
```

above ssh command I invoke after logged in to serverA. In serverB, I fire other commands for doing other stuffs.

I want to write a shell script which should do this for me but I am not sure how to call the ssh in nested form?

Is it possible to do the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ssh` can receive a `command` as an argument, then

```
 ssh -t uname@serverA ssh -t uname@serverB
```

should work

Comment: I got the error as ```Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
Permission denied, please try again.```

Comment: I again tried where I am getting the error as ```ssh: Could not resolve hostname ssh: Hostname and service name not provided or found```. may be it is considering ssh as hostname

Answer (score 4):

Most of the recent versions of ssh supports `jump host`. So you would be able to something like

```
 ssh -J uname@serverA uname@serverB
```

To simplify things, you can also add this information to `~/.ssh/config` file as follows

```
 Host serverA
  User uname

 Host serverB
  User uname
  ProxyJump serverA
```

Now `ssh serverB` is all that is needed to setup the nested ssh session

Answer (score 0):

You can put this information in `.ssh/config` file to proxy all you request to serverB through serverA

```
Host serverA
  User uname
  Hostname <ip/name of serverA>

Host serverB
  User uname
  Hostname <ip/name of serverB>
  ProxyCommand ssh -q -W %h:%p serverA
```

Now you can just `ssh serverB ls`.

Comment: ```/bin/bash: : No such file or directory```